# Flutter scraping two tables with the same class name

Tags: android, flutter, http, web-scraping

I am a beginner level flutter user, and I am building a mobile app in Android studio using Flutter. I want to scrape two tables from the page http://rte.arso.gov.si/zrak/kakovost%20zraka/podatki/dnevne_koncentracije.html, but they have the same class name (table class="online").

My code for getting the first table:

```
  Future extractData() async {

    // Getting the response from the targeted url
    final response = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse('http://rte.arso.gov.si/zrak/kakovost%20zraka/podatki/dnevne_koncentracije.html'));
    // Status Code 200 means response has been received successfully
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Getting the html document from the response
      var document = parser.parse(response.body);
      ;
      datalist.clear();
      datalist.add("");
      try {
        var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('online')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var cols = rows[0].getElementsByTagName('th');
        tabledata = List.generate(rows.length, (_) => List<String?>.generate(cols.length, (_) => null));
        var r = 0;
        for (var row in rows) {
          cols = row.getElementsByTagName(r == 0 ? 'th' : 'td');
          var c = 0;
          String tmpdata ="";
          for (var col in cols) {
            tabledata[r][c] = utf8.decode(latin1.encode(col.text), allowMalformed: true);
            c++;
          }
          r++;
        };
      } catch (e) {
        print('ERROR!');
      }
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
```

So how would I scrape the second table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you answered your own question with your code.
I don't have enough reputation to only comment so I will answer instead.

In your code, you get the first table with the following line:

```dart
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('online')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Actually the part `document.getElementsByClassName('online')` returns a list of all the elements with class name "online", which means the two tables.

You then get the first one by specifying `[0]` on that list (and skip right to the rows).

But if you specify `[1]` instead, you will get the second table (and if you have more tables one day, then you can continue increasing).

I hope that answers your question.